# Why does my Facebook Analytics have so many unknown values?

Tags: analytics, facebook-ads-manager

[image]

I've checked whether I install the code correctly and it seems fine. Do you know why is that?

Comment: I would look at the website's logs to see, but it could be a bot or a botnet.

Comment: it doesn't seem so. Look at the forth panel: Social Traffic Sources. I think bots cannot so much on social networks, especially when I pretty sure only Facebook is the source here